# Python PLY - something wrong with this grammar?

Tags: python, grammar, ply

I am trying to use Python PLY for a simple expression parser, and I can't get it to work. The code is [available at bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/malkarouri/klang/src/1489551249d3/klang.py), but the offending parts are:

First, the definitions:

```
def p_expr_minus(p):
    '''expr :   expr MINUS term'''
    p[0] = p[1]-p[3]
```

and

```
def p_term_divide(p):
    '''term :   term DIVIDE factor'''
    p[0] = p[1]/p[3]
```

seem to be inverted, and get me the results: 3-9 = 6 and 2 / 8 = 4.

Second, the parenthesis expression `factor: ( expr )` doesn't work. In particular, the part:

```
def p_factor_brackets(p):
    '''factor : OBRACKET expr CBRACKET'''
    p[0] = p[2]
```

doesn't function correctly. Parsing an expression such as `(9+7)` raises:

```
TypeError: unknown text at ')'
```

What is the source for these errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parser is fine, but you are doing something stupid in your `main()` method:

```
def main():
    data = "3*4+5*6-10"
    data = raw_input()
    print yacc.parse(data[::-1])
```

You are feeding the parser with the *reversed* string: `data[::-1]`!  No wonder that `(9+7)` gives an error, it is seen as `)7+9(` by the parser.  Just pass the real `data` and you'll be fine.